# Background-color in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, random, background

I am displaying a table that gets data from the data.json file. I built the arrow function getColor to consider the color for the values ​​of columns d, e according to the conditions. Top 10 rows I need to change random data every 3s for columns d and e.
I want when the value in the cell changes, the color also changes according to the condition of the arrow function getColor and will highlight the cell with that changed value in 1s with two backgrouds corresponding to 2 different colors. I'm not sure how to highlight background the cells that have changed values

below is what i did. You can also watch it at https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-perlman-qoi4wp?file=/src/App.js
the App.js file looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import data from './datafile/data.json';
import './styles.css'
export default function App() {

    const getColor = (a, b, c, value) =>{
      if(value > a && value < b){
          return "green";
      }else if(value > c && value < a){
          return "red"
      }
    }

    let ListData = data.list;
    let get10Data = ListData.slice(0, 10)

    const [list, setData] = useState(get10Data);
    const randomValue = (min, max) => {
        let value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
        return value;
    }
    const ChangeData = () => {
      get10Data.slice().map((info) => {
        if (info.a && info.b &&
          info.c && info.d && info.e !== undefined) {
          randomValue(info.b, info.c)
          return (
            setData(get10Data.slice(0, 5)),
            info.d = randomValue(info.b, info.c),
            info.e = randomValue(info.b, info.c)
            )
        }else {
            return ''
        }
      })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(ChangeData, 3000)
    }, [])  
    
    const Reacords = data.list.map(info => {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{info.name}</td>
                <td>{info.a}</td>
                <td>{info.b}</td>
                <td>{info.c}</td>
                <td className={getColor(info.a, info.b, info.c, info.d)}>{info.d}</td>
                <td className={getColor(info.a, info.b, info.c, info.e)}>{info.e}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    })

    return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>a</th>
                        <th>b</th>
                        <th>c</th>
                        <th>d</th>
                        <th>e</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {Reacords}
                </tbody>
            </table>

    );
}
```

the data.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "a": "ok",
  "list": [
      {
          "name": "A",
          "a": 50,
          "b": 90,
          "c": 30,
          "d": 40,
          "e": 85
      },
      {
          "name": "B",
          "a": 63,
          "b": 110,
          "c": 40,
          "d": 87,
          "e": 85
      },
      {
          "name": "C",
          "a": 48,
          "b": 85,
          "c": 25,
          "d": 30,
          "e": 43
      },
      {
        "name": "D",
        "a": 45,
        "b": 90,
        "c": 30,
        "d": 40,
        "e": 85
    },
    {
        "name": "E",
        "a": 63,
        "b": 110,
        "c": 40,
        "d": 87,
        "e": 85
    },
    {
        "name": "F",
        "a": 48,
        "b": 85,
        "c": 25,
        "d": 30,
        "e": 43
    },
    {
          "name": "G",
          "a": 50,
          "b": 90,
          "c": 30,
          "d": 40,
          "e": 85
      },
      {
          "name": "H",
          "a": 63,
          "b": 110,
          "c": 40,
          "d": 87,
          "e": 85
      },
      {
          "name": "I",
          "a": 48,
          "b": 85,
          "c": 25,
          "d": 30,
          "e": 43
      },
      {
        "name": "K",
        "a": 50,
        "b": 90,
        "c": 30,
        "d": 40,
        "e": 85
    },
    {
        "name": "L",
        "a": 63,
        "b": 110,
        "c": 40,
        "d": 87,
        "e": 85
    },
    {
        "name": "M",
        "a": 48,
        "b": 85,
        "c": 25,
        "d": 30,
        "e": 43
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope you can help. Please show an example of how it is done. random value generation part if anyone have another way can let me know.

Comment: so right now you are changing the text color, and what you want is to change the background color instead?
What about the css property `background-color`?

Comment: I want every time I change the value of a cell, the background will change color according to the color of the changed cell text.

Comment: is that what you want? https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-mestorf-x287t4

Comment: no, you are setting background-color for the whole column value. That's not what I want

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to build a random colour generator for you, but I'll demonstrate how to set backgrounds on your `tr`

First a function to be called that can return style attributes:

```
  const getRowColor = (a, b, c, value) => {
    if (value > a && value < b) {
      return { backgroundColor:'#F22' };
    } else if (value > c && value < a) {
      return { backgroundColor:'#2F2' };
    }
  };
```

Then on your table `tr` add the call to the function:

```
<tr style={getRowColor(info.a,info.b,info.c,info.d)}>
```

Comment: thank you, but you are setting background-color for the whole column value. That's not what I want :((((

Answer (score 0):

Just add additional css `background-color` properties to your existing classes:

```
.green {
  color: green;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.red {
  color: red;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

see it in action in [this fork of your codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-mestorf-x287t4)

Comment: no, what i want is only the cells that change the value to show the background color. You are making cells that do not change values ​​also have a background color